# Calling a Qt function from the Javascript side (QWebView)

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have a Qt project that can load any HTML page into a web view. I have the following code in `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView *view = new QWebView();

    view->resize(400, 500);
    view->load(QUrl("file:///absolute/path/to/my/html/file.html"));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This works fine, but I want to call a function from C++ side via Javascript loaded in `file.html` (loaded in `QWebView`).

So, having the following C++ function:

```
void sumOfNumbers (a, b)
{
   qDebug() << a + b;
}
```

I want to call it from Javascript side:

```
someMethod("sumOfNumber", 12, 23);
```

that will print in the console `35` (12 + 23).

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call a C++ function from JavaScript in a QWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615194/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-from-javascript-in-a-qwebview)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a dup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define the methods you want to call in a class that inherits from QObject.

From a QWebView, you can call `page()` to retrieve its QWebPage. With a QWebPage, you can call `mainFrame()` to retrieve its QWebFrame. QWebFrame has a `addToJavaScriptWindowObject()` method which lets you bind QObject's into the web context:

```
class MyObject {
public slots:
    void doSomething();
};

MyObject *foo = new MyObject;
myWebView->page()->mainFrame()->addJavaScriptToWindowObject("somefoo", foo);
```

Then from the javascript side I can call any slot or Q_INVOKABLE method on my QObject simply by referencing it by the name provided above ("somefoo" in this case):

```
somefoo.doSomething();
```

More info here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject

**Update** - adding the original example.

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void sumOfNumbers(int a, int b) {
        qDebug() << a + b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", new MyJavaScriptOperations);
    view->load(QUrl("file:///path/to/my/index.html"));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            myoperations.sumOfNumbers(12, 23);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can anyone tell what is main.moc ? Why is it included and what are the contents of "main.moc"

Comment: @ParthDoshi moc is the meta object compiler system that Qt uses to convert Qt-specific code in C++ (non-standard c++ code that Qt needs) into regular c++ code that the regular c++ compiler can understand. you don't normally need to interact or look at moc files

Comment: @ksimons I get `:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` `:-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` with your code. Any solutions?

Comment: @Niklas Have you rerun qmake? Maybe post your project file?

Answer (score 5):

Current accepted answer is outdated because [Qt moved to `WebEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html).

For `WebEngineView` the solution for calling Qt from JS is using [Qt WebChannel API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html)