# Call to Javascript function from Qt doesnt show output

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to call a Javascript function in my HTML file from QT using the `addToJavaScriptWindowObject` mwthod.  I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469295/calling-a-qt-function-from-the-javascript-side-qwebview) on StackOverflow and did exactly as the accepted answer.

My code is as follows

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
 Q_OBJECT  
 public:
  Q_INVOKABLE void sumOfNumbers(int a, int b) {
      qDebug() << a + b;
  }
 };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QWebView *view = new QWebView();
   view->resize(400, 500);
   view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", new  MyJavaScriptOperations);
   view->load(QUrl("file://C:/programs/index.html"));
   view->show();
   return a.exec();
 }

   #include "main.moc"
```

.pro file

```
 QT       += core

 QT       += gui

 QT       += webkit
 QT       += webkit webkitwidgets

 TARGET = QtJsonPostExample
 CONFIG   += console  
 CONFIG   -= app_bundle

 TEMPLATE = app

 SOURCES += main.cpp

 OTHER_FILES += \
 ../../../../programs/index.html
```

index.html

```
<html>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         myoperations.sumOfNumbers(12, 23);
    </script>
</body>
```

When I run the above QT project in Qt creator, it compiles correctly and even runs. I see the new window open up but the output , in this case the sum of 12+23= 35  isn't displayed in the `Application Output` window. Why is that so?

Why am I not able to view the output even though the program is running fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to enable debug output. Are you sure you built in debug mode? Try adding a qDebug() << "Test"; to your main function to check.