# Calling Qt slot from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qt, callback, qwebenginepage

I'm using a QWebEnginePage class for rendering my webpage. And i need to implement callback function. So first i want to register my slot in JS and call this slot from JS when it needed (for example, after click button on the webpage). I tried to do like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975658/qt-qwebview-javascript-callback), but it not that i need, because it illustrate only calling JS function from Qt and recieving the result, but i need callback. Is it possible to implement?

in earlier versions of Qt there was a module qtwebkit and my goal could be achieved like discribed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469295/calling-a-qt-function-from-the-javascript-side-qwebview) using addToJavaScriptWindowObject method. But how to do that with qtwebenginewidgets module which doesn't have that and even similar method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [QWebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-index.html) you can use [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html) in order to communicate with your JS

Create a proxy object to communicate with Qt from JS

```
// This Object will be registered in the web channel
class MyJSObj : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyJSObj(QObject * poParent = Q_NULLPTR);

   Q_INVOKABLE int foo(); // call from JS
};
```

In your cpp code

```
// Create proxy object
m_poMyJSObj = new MyJSObj(this);

// Create channel
m_poWebView = new QWebEngineView(this);
QWebChannel * poChannel = new QWebChannel();
m_poWebView->page()->setWebChannel(poChannel);

// Register your proxy object
const QString oJSObjectName = "mJSQtObject"; // use in JS to call Qt functions
poChannel->registerObject(oJSObjectName, m_poMyJSObj);
```

In JS

```
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            // now you retrieve your object
            var JSQtObject = channel.objects.mJSQtObject;
            // call Qt function from JS
            var qtValue = JSQtObject.foo();
        });
```

Please note that you will have to include the [qwebchannel.js](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html) on the HTML side

Comment: Note that when in strict mode JS/TS compiler will complain that there's no such object such as "qt.webChannelTransport", so just use "window.qt.webChannelTransport"